# Enable dyntopo in Blender 2.80 Beta

Tags: sculpting

I downloaded the Blender 2.80 Beta and wanted to try some sculpting, but I can't find where to enable dyntopo. Is it not supported in Blender 2.80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dyntopo could be found in the "Active Tool" tab

[image]